# BeautifulSoup: Extracting Value from Children nodes

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have following html:

```
<td class="section">
    <div style="margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:-10px; ">
    <span class="username"><a href="user.php?id=xx">xxUsername</a></span>
    </div>
    <br>
<span class="comment">
A test comment
</span>
</td>
```

All I want to retrieve xxUsername and comment text within SPAN tag. So far I have done this:

```
results = soup.findAll("td", {"class" : "section"})
```

It does fetches ALL html blocks of the pattern I mentioned above. Now I want to retrieve all children value within a single loop? Is it possible? If not then how do I fetch child nodes information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like this. It basically does what you did above - first iterates through all `section`-classed `td`'s and then iterates through all `span` text within. This prints out the class, just in case you needed to be more restrictive:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: html = # Your html here

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

In [4]: for td in soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'section'}):
   ...:     for span in td.find_all('span'):
   ...:         print span.attrs['class'], span.text
   ...:         
['username'] xxUsername
['comment'] 
A test comment
```

Or with a more-convoluted-than-necessary one-liner that will store everything back in your list:

```
In [5]: results = [span.text for td in soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'section'}) for span in td.find_all('span')]

In [6]: results
Out[6]: [u'xxUsername', u'\nA test comment\n']
```

Or on that same theme, a dictionary with the keys being a tuple of the classes and the values being the text itself:

```
In [8]: results = dict((tuple(span.attrs['class']), span.text) for td in soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'section'}) for span in td.find_all('span'))

In [9]: results
Out[9]: {('comment',): u'\nA test comment\n', ('username',): u'xxUsername'}
```

Assuming this one is bit closer to what you want, I would suggest rewriting as:

```
In [10]: results = {}

In [11]: for td in soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'section'}):
   ....:     for span in td.find_all('span'):
   ....:         results[tuple(span.attrs['class'])] = span.text
   ....:         

In [12]: results
Out[12]: {('comment',): u'\nA test comment\n', ('username',): u'xxUsername'}
```

Comment: Why something like this will not work? *for user in td.find_all('span',{'class': 'comhead','class': 'comment'}):*

Answer (score 1):

To get text from either `username` or `comment` `<span>` elements:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for el in soup('span', ['username', 'comment']):
    print el.string,
```

#### Output

```
xxUsername 
A test comment
```

Comment: I don't get why your code is not working for me. It's just returning *None* to me.

Comment: @Volatil3: My code uses beautifulsoup4 (note: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` import). Check that you are not using 3 version (that uses `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup` import).

Comment: I had just copied this line: *for el in soup('span', ['username', 'comment']):*

Comment: @Volatil3: given html in your question, my code produces the output shown in the answer.